# How do I have my UIViewController respond to a non-touch event?

Tags: events, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, uicontrol

Working with iPhone SDK 3.2 --

I have a complex custom UIControl that handles touches on the child controls.  In certain cases, I want the parent UIControl to pass an event to the UIViewController, which will then take action outside the control.  How do I do this cleanly?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up handling this with

> [control addTarget:self
>   action:@selector(action:)
>   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

in the UIViewController

and

> [self
>   sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

in the UIControl

Comment: So what is control in this example? An instance of UIControl directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can override [hitTest:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:) in the UIControl and return nil when you determine that the touch should be handled by the parent.

Comment: Clever approach, thanks.  If this were Flash/ActionScript, I would have the UIViewController listen for a custom event from the parent UIControl; and I would dispatch this event in the UIControl when my conditions were met.  That approach makes a lot of sense to me, too -- is it ever used in Objective C?

Comment: I've tried using touchesBegan:, touchesMoved:, etc in the VC but you only get touches that are not handled by any UIControl so that may or may not work for what you want.